# Python datetime DST when tzinfo is None

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, dst, tzinfo

Calling the method `timestamp` at the last Sunday of march returns:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> before = datetime.fromisoformat("2023-03-26 02:00:01")
>>> after = datetime.fromisoformat("2023-03-26 03:00:01")
>>> print(before.tzinfo)
None
>>> print(after.tzinfo)
None
>>> after.timestamp() - before.timestamp()
0.0
```

They are equal even they are separated by an hour. I was expecting that daylight saving time was not handled when tzinfo is `None`

Meanwhile, when using the subtract operator, it catches the difference

```py
>>> after - before
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
```

Comment: Note another "specialty" here: "2023-03-26 02:00:01" didn't even exist if you had a DST transition on that date! Clocks went from 1:59 am straight to 3:00 am (DST inactive to active). Nevertheless, the `timestamp()` method plays it like there was a transition ?!...

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp

> Naive `datetime` instances are assumed to represent local time and this method relies on the platform C mktime() function to perform the conversion.

"naive" means without tzinfo, so the `timestamp` method implicitly treats them as local time, hence the zero difference you see.

Meanwhile the `after - before` date math treats them as abstract datetimes with no timezone, so the resulting timedelta does not take DST into account.